# How do I upgrade PHP on CentOS and Kloxo?

Tags: php, yum

I need to upgrade PHP so that I can upgrade joomla on my dedicated server. I have:

- kloxo 6.1.6
- php-5.2.17-1
- Linux CentOS-55-64-minimal 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I searched everywhere and I could only find that PHP 5.3 isn't compatible with zend. I would like to upgrade to 5.2.4, which is the minimum for joomla 1.6 and 1.7.

I tried to run:

```
yum update php.x86_64
```

Which is the PHP package installed, but it didn't work.

This is a production server with quite a few users across many sites, so I wanted to do it as safely as possible.

Is it safe to run "yum update"? It showed me 6 packages to install and 125 packages to update, including a kernel. Is that safe? I haven't touched kloxo's yum repositories.

**Update:**

I just successfully ran "yum update".

Now I think I need to know how to add a new repository that has the 5.2.4 and how to update to that specific version.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just update to CentOS 6? It has newer versions of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Remi's repository has always been a good choice for PHP (and mysql) versions beyond the official distro releases:

http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en

You'll need to setup the repo and then make sure the specific version you want is available.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

My PHP configuration was ignoring the parse_ini_file function, which is used since joomla 1.6.
This was a default behaviour of kloxo, which has brought me a few headaches and endless wasted hours.